# How to pass header parameters while calling a rest api using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest

I am calling a rest api using $.ajax method. My api is expecting some request headers. But when I am passing the request headers in ajax method I am getting 404 error. Here is my code-

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:9000/api/someapi/82",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { 'emailAddReceiver': 'sample@gmail.com' },
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

I am getting 404 error on this api call via ajax but when I am calling it using a rest client and passing the request header from there its working fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: nope didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following sample

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:9000/api/someapi/82",
   type: "GET",
   timeout: 15000,
   beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('emailAddReceiver', 'sample@gmail.com');},      
   success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
              alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }  
});
```

Comment: Its throwing : - OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/api/someapi/82 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I am using jquery 1.8.1 version, do I need to change it?

Comment: I have introduced timeout and a failure function in the answer above. change the timeout as per your need and also see what error are you getting.

Comment: Its throwing error in the jquery library. In the console it looks like this-
OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/api/student/sendotp/82?_=1450293425824 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Can you try changing the jquery lib version ? see if that helps